# is there a way to stream tamil tweets?

Tags: tweepy, tamil

I want to stream Tamil tweets using a key word. For example I need to stream the tweets containing the word "கனா". I wrote some code but could not be able to stream all the tweets containing the keyword. It returns a few tweets. How to solve this issue?

```py
access_token = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN" access_token_secret = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET" consumer_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY" consumer_secret = "ENTER YOUR API SECRET"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
         op.write(data)
         return True

    def on_error(self, status):
         print(status)

# This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API

l = StdOutListener() auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret) auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret) stream = Stream(auth, l)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
query = "கனா"
# Language code (follows ISO 639-1 standards)
language = "ta"

# Calling the user_timeline function with our parameters
a = api.search(q=query, lang=language)
```